What would "what is your grade?" mean in Australian English?
Yesterday, I was at this Westfield shopping Centre in New South Wales. Some random man came up to me and talked to me about the usual "children donations" thing. He wanted to ask what I do, and I said "I am in education". Then he asked "with kids", and I said "adults too". Then, he asked me "What is your grade?" I didn't fully understand this as in Australia, people say Year 1, not Grade 1 or first grade for the class level a student is in, and also, people here say mark, not grade, for the score one receives in class.
I just responded, "All ages".
Then, he mentioned some other random nonsense. After that, he suddenly asked me, "What is your grade"? again. Then, he went like "Is it math, science?" It looks like he meant grade as the name of the subject.
The only other grade I have come across was the ranking of like a military soldier.

"What is your grade?" should mean what grade are you teaching? You said adults and kids, but that doesn't say addition (2nd-grade math) or biology (10th-grade science). The dialog sounds like the question was what subject, not kids/adults. What do you teach, not who.

Yes, I said "adults and kids" only cause he said "so like kids" before asking me "what is my grade". Also in Australia, people dont say second grade or tenth grade. Its Year 2 and Year 10, so I was confused. Also, adults arent in second or tenth grade lol. They would be in university if even in school, which does not have grades. Also, teachers can teach more than 1 grade level. So, does "What is your grade?" in this context mean "What subject do you teach?"

The miscommunication stemmed from a non-native. You don't use "grades" but he did.

What is "the usual 'children donations' thing"?

@YosefBaskin Grades is used only in North America to refer to the score one gets in a class or the class level someone is in. In Australia, it is year-number for the class level and mark for the score.

@TimR This sometimes happens in these big cities where some person randomly comes to you with a tablet and gives a lecture about how children in third-world countries are suffering. They try to guilt you into donating. No idea if these are scams or not.

Honey, that's a scam for sure. [honey is sweet]. Some random guy (driver) blocked my line of vision when I was turning right. I gently pointed it out, and his passenger heard me. He was so nasty to me, saying, "My job is to make sure [whatever]. You don't want to hear what I said to him. :)

I guess at this point there's no way to know where the man who asked you this question was from.
In the US, "grade" means your year in the educational process. We number from "first grade" to "twelfth grade", first grade being about age 6 up to twelfth being about 17. Most American children go to "kindergarten" before grade 1. If you go to college, there's a totally different system of counting. First year of college is "freshman", then "sophomore", "junior" and "senior". If you take classes as an adult, but not working toward a college degree, this is generally called "adult ed" or "continuing ed", and there is no grade number. Like I once took a couple of classes in photography at a local college. They called it "continuing ed". (Some call it "lifelong learning" but this just sounds cumbersome to me.)
Just to make things more complicated, 9th grade is sometimes called "high school freshman", 10th "high school sophomore", 11th "high school junior", and 12th "high school senior". If it's obvious in context that we're talking about high school and not college, you can just drop the "high school" part.
If you ask a teacher "what grade", that means, "what grade do you teach?" If the teacher teaches children of more than one age, she might say the grade that she teaches most often, or might say "grades 2 and 3". Likewise if a teacher primarily teaches 8th grade but also teaches some adult classes, she would probably just say "8th grade" unless it was obviously relevant that she also taught adults.
"Grade" can also mean the score one got on a test or an overall score for a class. If someone asked, "What grade are you in?", the person might answer "Ninth". But if you asked, "What grade did you get on the test?", they'd answer "85" or "B+" or whatever makes sense given the scoring system.
Sometimes Americans will say "what year" instead of "what grade". It's understood but it's fairly rare.
I have never heard someone use "grade" to mean "subject". But as I say, I have no idea where this person was from, so that might be what they say in some other country. Or if English is not his first language, this may just be a translation problem.

Perhaps. The thing is I mentioned "all ages" as well as "both kids and adults", so I was confused what he meant by "what grade?" He asked it again, and then immediately after he said "like math, science?"

Right. That's what I was referring to in my last paragraph. It sounds like by "grade" he meant "subject". I've never heard that meaning from anyone from any English-speaking country I've talked to ... but maybe he's from some other country or some other dialect. Or maybe he's not a native English speaker himself and is confused. Of course all I know about the conversation is what you related above, so I can't do more than guess.

In Australia, I don’t think many would know “grade” means the year-level of primary and secondary school unless they watched American tv and films frequently enough that use this term. Americans would understand Year 1 or first year means first grade or Grade 1 easily when talking about school cause it is the first year of school.
Australians tend to say mark instead of grade when talking about the score one gets in class. I don’t think they will understand grade also means mark. Americans tend to use grade, but they do say mark you down or make off some points, so they could know mark.

@Megas Welll... If you told an American, "My son is in year 3 in school", he MIGHT guess or figure out that you mean "he's in 3rd grade". But he would find it confusing and unclear and not at all obvious. If you told an American, "My son got high marks in school", yes, he'd understand that fine.

That is only cause it is almost rare for anyone in America to say Year 3 for third grade, but its not that confusing cause third grade in America literally means the third school year someone is studying in.
